# LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, классы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пример взят из книги, там не было только строк с include и setlocale

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
const int max_len = 255;
class my_string {
public:
    void assign(const char* st);
    int length() const { return len; }
    void print() const {
        cout << s << "\n Длина: " << len << endl;
    }
private:
    char s[max_len];
    int len;
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    my_string one;
    my_string two;
    char three[40] = { "Меня зовут Чарльз Бэббидж." };
    one.assign("Меня зовут Алан Тьюринг.");
    two.assign(three);
    cout << three;
    cout << "\n Dlina: " << strlen(three) << endl;
    if (one.length()<=two.length())
    {
        one.print();
    }
    else
    {
        two.print();
    }
}
```

Ошибка: LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: void __thiscall my_string::assign(char const *)" (?assign@my_string@@QAEXPBD@Z)"

Comment: Ничего не поделаешь. Если это все, что есть в книге, то в книге - ошибка.

Comment: А что за книга? чтоб посмотреть, все ли вы из нее переписали и не потеряли ли где-то определение функции `assign`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема заключается в том, что у метода `assign` нет реализации.
напишите реализацию `assign`.